# ScriptMethod in ASPX page, called from browser, IIS6 Returning 404

Tags: c#, jquery, configuration, iis-6, mime-types

I have code which works on the dev environment (my machine), 
though doesn't work on IIS6

I have a method in an ASPX page which has a footprint similar to this:

```
 [WebMethod()]
 [ScriptMethod()]
 public static string HelloWorld(string name)
  { 
       return 'Hi '+name;
  }
```

When I look at the console on the browser, I can see my script call this method, though IIS returns a 404 not found.

The script does a http POST to this url: 
http://mydomain.com/myPage.aspx/HelloWorld

I am guessing it has something to do with mime types on IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to this, 
The problem was caused by two things.

Firstly, I needed to add this to the Web.Config

```
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Then , the other issue was the use of a tool for url rewriting called UrlRewritingNet 
(http://www.urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html)

One of the ways to configure this module, is to put in in IIS6 as an ISAPI filter , matching a wild card * , so if no file extension was matched, this filter would run the query.

The way I got around the second problem was to do an XML query to my service, and not a json one. Which then uses a url with a file extension when making the call.

Hope this helps